# Why not use CBC, not send IV, and assume first plaintext block is garbage?

Tags: initialization-vector, cbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using CBC with fixed IV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/using-cbc-with-fixed-iv)

Forgive me if this has been asked before, I looked but haven't seen any answers that suit.

Is there any danger in using CBC, encrypting a message plus one initial block of garbage, discarding the IV, and when decrypting, use any random IV, and then discard the resulting initial plaintext block?

I'm sure I'm not the only one to confront this question.

Comment: This question is very similar to [Using CBC with fixed IV](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/using-cbc-with-fixed-iv)