# CBC with fixed IV but changing data

Tags: aes, initialization-vector, cbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using CBC with fixed IV](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/using-cbc-with-fixed-iv)

I am using AES in CBC mode.

For some reasons I have some issues for transmiting the IV. So I am using a fixed IV.

If the first 128bits of the message, change on every message (like a timestamp).
Does that can moderate the issue of having a fixed IV ?